# How to remove word with extra delimiter from given string?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have following string.

```
var str = "abc, abcd, abc, abcf, abc, abc";
```

I want to remove `abc` from a given string with `, (space)`. Basically, I want output something like below.

```
var output = "abcd, abcf";
```

Note:- If possible give regex solution(with one replace only).

Things I have tried:-

1) 1st approach

```js
var str = "abc, abcd, abc, abcf, abc, abc";
var w = "abc";
var output = str.split(", ").filter(x => !(x === w)).join(", ");
console.log(output);
```

Here I have used `split`, then `filter` and then `join`, basically 3 array operations. (which **I think** not good when performance is concerned).

2) 2nd approach

```js
var str = "abc, abcd, abc, abcf, abc, abc";
var w = "abc";
var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + w + "\\b", "ig");
var output = str.replace(regex,"");
output = output.replace(/, , /ig,", ");
output = output.replace(/^, |, $/ig,"");
console.log(output);
```

Here I am using three times `replace`.

Is it possible achieve in simpler way?

Answer (score 4):

You may use this `.replace` code:

```js
var w = 'abc';

var str = "abc, abcd, abc, abcf, abc, abc";

str = str.replace(new RegExp("\\b" + w + "(?:, |$)", "g"), '')
         .replace(/, $/, '');

console.log(str);
//=> "abcd, abcf"
```

- In the first `.replace` call we are replacing word `abc` with the trailing `", "`.
- We effectively use this regex first: `/\babc(?:, |$)/`
- In the second `.replace` call we remove any remaining trailing `", "` in the string.
- We effectively use this regex second time: `/, $/` to remove any left over `", "`

[Performance Test Link](https://jsperf.com/remove-word-with-trailing-comma)

Comment: This answer seems better than mine

Comment: This regex is doing its job in a great way, but OP's first approach is a bit tad faster, no?

Comment: @sertsedat Is 3 array operations are faster than 1 regex operation?

Comment: http://jsben.ch/w9EsA I ran a performance test tool. indeed array one is a tad faster

Comment: Thanks so much @sertsedat, so looks like regex code is bit faster.

Comment: @sertsedat Thank you. Link would be very helpful

Comment: that's weird. I run the same test a few times, sometimes array one is faster sometimes regex. Why is it so volatile?

Comment: @anubhava If you run different test, then please share the output of that test(on any other site)

Comment: Here is extensive performance comparison test: https://jsperf.com/remove-word-with-trailing-comma You need to click on `Run Again` to start test. I am always getting `regex way` faster than `array way` with longer string that @sertsedat has provided.

Answer (score 2):

Using one `replace()`

```js
var str = "abc, abcd, abc, abcf, abc, abc";

var rep = "abc";

var r = new RegExp("(, "+rep+"(?![a-z]))|("+rep+"(?![a-z]), )","g");
 
str = str.replace(r, "");

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two more way of doing above.

1) Using single `.replace()`

```js
var str = "abc, abcd, abc, abcf, abc, abc";
var w = "abc";
var regex = new RegExp(", " + w + "\\b", "g");
var output = (", " + str).replace(regex,"").substr(2);
console.log(output);
```

2) Using `.reduce()`

```js
var str = "abc, abcd, abc, abcf, abc, abc";
var w = "abc";
var output = str.split(", ").reduce((a, x, i) => {
                    if(x !== w){
                      a = a + ", "+ x;
                    }
                    return a;
                  },'').substr(2);
console.log(output);
```